# Select only max value in joined table with some where clauses

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Well, after i researched and tried multiple ways (mostly found here on stackoverflow) i still dont get it working.

I have one mysql table like this (shortened and the time would be in timestamp of course):

```
id docid wardid version approved endingtime
 1   1      1      1        1    5 days
 2   1      1      2        1    20 days
 3   1      1      3        0    40 days
 4   2      2      1        0    30 days
 5   2      2      2        1    50 days
```

and two other tables with some values like `name` for the `docid` and `wardid`

Now, what it want is to select all rows (only one of each docid entry) which aren't approved or are within a specific endingtime but only the one with the highest version. So in this example i want to get only the row with id 3
It sounds pretty simple as i write this but i got completely lost. Not enough, the idiot in me erased all tries (but the last):

```
SELECT MAX(dv.version), dv.docid, dv.id, dv.approved, dv.endingtime, d.name, w.name
FROM (doc_versions as dv
    LEFT JOIN docs as d ON d.id = dv.docid
    LEFT JOIN wards as w ON w.id = d.wardid
WHERE (approved < 1 AND ...)
OR (dv.endingtime < $time AND ...)
GROUP BY dv.docid
```

Hopefully you can help me out. I think this is the worst try (which made me ragequit yesterday ;))

edit: 
my last try which seems to work, have to try it out some more.

```
SELECT v1.docs_id, v1.id as docversion, v1.approved, v1.approver, d.name as docname, w.name as wardname, d.wards_id as wardsid, v1.validity_endtime as deadline, v1.creator
        FROM 
        (
            doc_versions v1
            LEFT JOIN docs as d ON d.id = v1.docs_id 
            LEFT JOIN wards as w ON w.id = d.wards_id
        ) 
        INNER JOIN
        (
          SELECT MAX(version) version, docs_id
          FROM doc_versions
          GROUP BY docs_id
        ) v2
          ON v1.version = v2.version
          AND v1.docs_id = v2.docs_id
        WHERE (approved < 1 AND approver = ".$userid.($wardid > 0 ? ' AND wardsid = '.$wardid : '').")
        OR (v1.validity_endtime < $time AND creator = ".$userid.($wardid > 0 ? ' AND wardsid = '.$wardid : '').")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
SELECT *
FROM doc_versions dv1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(version) version
      FROM doc_versions
     WHERE (approved = 0 OR endingtime < $time ...)
     GROUP BY id
) dv2 ON dv1.id = dv2.id AND dv2.version = dv1.version
```

In the subquery you build a table with each id and the maximum valid version; in the outer query you join the initial table on those two values.

Comment: Thanks, thats nearly the same i just tried, the only difference is that my WHERE clause is out of the inner join. i'll edit my post. thanks for your help. have to check.

Comment: I just tried and took a look where the difference is. yours will give me some more unwanted results. actually i would love to know why but can't invest any more time (at the moment) in it. I will follow this though.